# height=100% does not work when the out container's height is stretched by other element?

Tags: css

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ok7rj8my/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxLeftWrapper">
        <input/>
        <input/>
    </div>
    <div class="boxRightWrapper">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div , input {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient : horizontal;
    -webkit-box-align : center;
    -webkit-box-pack : center;
}

input {
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-box-flex : 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.boxLeftWrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient : vertical;
    -webkit-box-align : center;
    -webkit-box-pack : center;
    -webkit-box-flex : 1;
}

.boxRightWrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

height: 100% does not work for .boxRightWrapper. why? is there any way to let boxRightWrapper fit height of .container?

Comment: Is the below answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If the container does not have a fixed height then its children will not be able to use height as a percentage as the container has not yet had it's height determined.

there is a css only work around which i have seen used which is to affectively suck the div into the space that is left under it

```
.boxRightWrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom:-9999px;
    padding-bottom:9999px;
}
```

then so that you don't see all the space it creates hide the overflow. Oh also removed box-align centre as that was pushing the box to the bottom.

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient : horizontal;
    /* -webkit-box-align : center; */
    -webkit-box-pack : center;
}
```

heres a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/vqgt07ds/